# agrep output approximate macthing

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison, agrep

Having

```
 agrep('timothy', c('timo','tim','timoth', 'timothys'), max.distance = 0.01, value=TRUE)
```

I want to output the original string and all possible results together in a data frame as below.

```
Original Replace1 Replace2
timothy  timoth   timothys
```

Is this possible or is there a better function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally keep it in "long" format vs wide (you can always transformit later):

```
data.frame(
  original = "timothy",
  replacement = agrep('timothy', c('timo','tim','timoth', 'timothys'), max.distance = 0.01, value=TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
##   original replacement
## 1  timothy      timoth
## 2  timothy    timothys
```

You likely want to do this more than once, so I'd make that a function. And, since the output of `agrep()` *can* be `character(0)`, we need to handle that so we'll add in a helper function, too:

```
`%|l0%` <- function(x, y) if (length(x) == 0) y else x

agrep_to_data_frame <- function(pattern, x, max.distance=0.01, costs=NULL) {
  data.frame(
    original = pattern,
    replacement = agrep(pattern, x, max.distance = max.distance, value=TRUE) %|l0% NA_character_,
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  )
}
```

And, now it's a single call which you can use in `purrr::map2()` or `mapply()`, etc.

```
agrep_to_data_frame('timothy', c('timo','tim','timoth', 'timothys'))
##   original replacement
## 1  timothy      timoth
## 2  timothy    timothys
```